# How to get enumerate with roman numerals

Tags: enumerate

Like

```
I. First item
Followed by non indented text

II. Second item
Followed by non indented text
```

While having non indented text in it. This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelindent=1em, listparindent=0em]

\item first item

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `label=\Roman*. ` it is in the manual for the package

Comment: Thanks, was trying something similar, but it wasnt working. Shouldnt there be a point after `I`. Also can I make it in bold ?

Comment: `\label=\bfseries\Roman*.` What do you mean about the "point after I"? This will give **I.**, **II.** etc. If you don't want the . then omit  it.

Comment: yes, I just found label=\textbf{\Roman*}, What about the point ?

Comment: daleif and Andrew have both shown how to have a point (it's just literal text so type a `.`)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. This screen is too small.